# Using get with back-tics and paste in R

Tags: r, get

I am trying to pull some data from the OpenEI database using their API and get it into a useable format, however I am having trouble extracting some of the data. The example is so:

```
library(RCurl)
library(rjson)

rate_name <- 'Data:B386166e-7e84-42fa-b8ae-1a4b07fb05d9'

data <- getURL(paste('http://en.openei.org/services/rest/utility_rates?version=2&format=json&detail=full&getpage=' ,rate_name, '&detail=full', sep = ''))

data2 <- fromJSON(data)

x <- 3
```

Now:

> data2$items[[1]]$`energyratestructure/period3/tier1rate`

```
 [1] 0.0573
```

And:

```
 > paste('data2$items[[1]]$`energyratestructure/period', x, '/tier1rate`', sep = '')
[1] "data2$items[[1]]$`energyratestructure/period3/tier1rate`"
```

But:

```
> get(paste('data2$items[[1]]$`energyratestructure/period', x, '/tier1rate`', sep = ''))
Error in get(paste("data2$items[[1]]$`energyratestructure/period", x,  : 
object 'data2$items[[1]]$`energyratestructure/period3/tier1rate`' not found
```

I am in need of a way to get the value of the object made in `paste()` -- the first object. This might be easy, but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `get` to extract part of an object. Just use the standard indexing operator `[[`, and construct the label with `paste`.

```
data2$items[[1]][[paste0("energyratestructure/period", x, "/tier1rate")]]
```

(To clarify, in case you weren't aware already: `x$y` is the same as `x[["y"]]`, where `"y"` is a string giving the name of the element you want to extract.)

Comment: Yep -- don't mind me, just a lowly engineer trying to do some programming on the side...